# How to remove user from all database roles in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server

The following query selects all database roles, which member is @myUser:

```
SELECT
    p.name AS userRoleName
FROM sys.database_role_members rm
INNER JOIN sys.database_principals p ON  p.principal_id = rm.role_principal_id
INNER JOIN sys.database_principals m ON  m.principal_id = rm.member_principal_id
WHERE m.name = @myUser;
```

For each databaase roles listed above I have to run:

```
ALTER ROLE [database_role_name] DROP MEMBER @myUser;
```

How to combine two above queries in one T-SQL procedure?

Comment: You'll need to compile a dynamic query, if you're on a recently version of SQL Server with `STRING_AGG`, and then execute that.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with dynamic SQL. I assume you have `STRING_AGG` available in your version of SQL Server:

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) =
(SELECT
    STRING_AGG(
        CAST(N'ALTER ROLE ' + QUOTENAME(p.name) + N' DROP MEMBER ' + QUOTENAME(@myUser) + N';'
        AS nvarchar(max))
    , NCHAR(10))
FROM sys.database_role_members rm
INNER JOIN sys.database_principals p ON  p.principal_id = rm.role_principal_id
INNER JOIN sys.database_principals m ON  m.principal_id = rm.member_principal_id
WHERE m.name = @myUser
);

-- PRINT @sql  -- for testing
EXEC (@sql)
```